# HelpScout and SSO - Initiate Single Sign-On?

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, saml

I'm a SAML newbie, working on setting up [SAML SSO for HelpScout](https://docs.helpscout.com/article/877-enabling-sso-in-your-account) using [the `saml2-js` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js). My app will be serving as its own identity provider.

If a user on my site wants to log in to HelpScout, do I a) send them to a HelpScout URL (if so which one?) or b) hit a HelpScout API endpoint (if so which one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out HelpScount doesn't need SSO for my use case. They have it for some use cases that I haven't yet encountered.